# jQuery drag and drop not "accepting" my drop

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

This is probably a simple thing I am over looking, but I am trying to implement drag and drop on my website. It does not seem to be working though. I created a [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UcU5t/) that is exhibiting the odd behavior. Here is my code:

```
$(function() {
    $("li", "#hostsList").draggable({
        revert: "invalid",
        cursor: "move",
        containment: "document"
    });

    $("#selectedHosts").droppable({
        accept: "#hostsList > li",
        drop: function(event, ui) {
        alert("Dropped!");
    }
});
```

In the fiddle, I am trying to drag "test #1" or "test #2" into the green div area, but it isn't working. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Like this ? http://jsfiddle.net/q47Lc/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default jQueryUI droppables are set to only accept draggables when at least 50% of its width is over the droppable area. Because you have not set a width on your draggables, they are much wider than double your droppables width.

You can remedy this by setting

```
tolerance:"touch"
```

on your droppable which will make it accept any element dropped when touching it as in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/UcU5t/7/) or

```
tolerance:"pointer"
```

which will cause your droppable to accept any draggable element that is dropped while the mouse pointer is over the droppable, as in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/UcU5t/5/).

Alternatively, you could set a width on your draggables which is less than twice the width of your droppable area, or combine a set width with one of the above options for a better user experience.